# Can't install ruby 1.9.2 with rvm in mountain lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I installed rvm and now trying to install ruby 1.9.2, when I do the following :

```
~% rvm install 1.9.2
No binary rubies available for: ///ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary  rubies.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/info/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/info/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/info/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, please note I'm using mountain lion OS X and I already installed ruby 1.9.3 with rvm

```
~% rvm list 

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Do you have any clue what i'm doing wrong here ?

Please note that rvm requirements give me the following results : https://gist.github.com/edb19698cd23e52999f5

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? It looks like it's starting the compilation process.

Comment: No binary rubiest available , and no it is freezing at this stage

Comment: Are you sure it's not busy compiling?

Comment: no at this stage i'm supposed to get a progress bar with some stuff to be downloaded, but i've been running this for 15 mins now and i got nothing yet , even with the message as u can c

Comment: It takes longer than 15 mins to build ruby on some machines, are you sure it's not just working?

Comment: ya i'm 100% sure , i've been waiying for 40 mins now , and nothing , it still at Configuring yaml in /Users/info/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.you want me to repat the process ?

Comment: what version of rvm are you using? rvm --version

Comment: Just did it yesterday. Was waiting on this screen too. Then realized this were just requirements, pressed `q` to exit (seems like it opens requirements in vim), installation continued. On this screen, do you have colon in left bottom corner?

Comment: ~% rvm --version

rvm 1.16.8 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Comment: @SimonBagreev no such a thing like to press q , there is no vim

Comment: any idea what would be the cause of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work for me
make sure RVM is up to date

```
rvm get head

CC=/usr/bin/gcc rvm install 1.9.2 --enable-shared
```

note: /usr/bin/gcc ==> path/to/gcc

Answer (score 0):

RVM just upgraded their version and added binary ruby option, all it means is that it will download and compile ruby on your machine because it didn't find an appropriate binary. This is not an error, just an info. It looks like it is just taking it's time, it could take up to 30 minutes to download/compile requirements.

Comment: but it's not moving at all , no progress at all , the past 40 mins i'm just getting this : % rvm install 1.9.2
No binary rubies available for: ///ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/info/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/info/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/info/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
and nothing more at all

Comment: check your activity monitor or whatever you use to see process CPU and memory usage, it could take this long, it really depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: but that never happened to me before , i installed so many packages before and never faced the same problem , please check out this http://screencast.com/t/GB9sAY5UKZad